# Migrating VMWare Fusion Bootcamp Partition to New Mac

Tags: vmware-fusion

What is the best way for me to migrate my VMWare Fusion Bootcamp Partition to a new MAC.  Preferably I would like to import the current bootcamp partition in as a strict virtual machine on the new mac, instead of in bootcamp.  The "older mac" is about two years old, so I don't think there will be any compatibility issues, but i do not have enough disc space on the old machine to import it as a virtual machine, and then migrate it.
Thanks for the help.